# Como leer cadenas de una estructura pasada por referencia

Tags: c, struct, paso-por-referencia, string

Esta es mi Estructura

```
typedef struct{
    char Nombre[20];
  }Cliente;
```

Y me piden una funcion que capture el nombre por medio de la estructura y realice esta función

```
 void Captura_cliente(Cliente *client){
     printf("Escriba el nombre: \n");
     scanf("%s",client->Nombre);
  }
```

Estoy leyendo un libro y este dice que cuando se leen cadenas se puede escribir el scanf("%s",var); sin necesidad de usar el & pero tengo duda porque en varios programas que hice en clase utilizamos el & para lectura de cadenas.

¿Cual es la forma correcta de leer las cadenas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible forma, tal y como estás haciendo, es usar `scanf( )` y usando como formato el `"%s"`. De esta manera, a la función `scanf( )` hay que pasarle **un puntero** a un *buffer* o zona de memoria en la cual se puedan escribir los caracteres leídos.

Si estamos usando una formación, cuyo tamaño es conocido en tiempo de compilación, y sabiendo que en C una formación *decae* a un tipo puntero, basta con hacer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  char buffer[100];
  scanf( "%s", buffer );
  printf( "%s", buffer );

  return 0;
}
```

Si la formación está **dentro** de una `struct`, pues igual:

```
struct dummy {
  char buffer[100];
};

int main( void ) {
  struct dummy d;
  scanf( "%s", d.buffer );
  printf( "%s", d.buffer );

  return 0;
}
```

¿ Y si pasamos la `struct` como puntero ?. En ese caso, lo que nos interesa es **el desplazamiento relativo dentro** de la `struct`. La dirección final que estamos buscando, en la que poder escribir, es `dirección_base + dirección_relativa`. Con lo cual, se nos abre un abanico de opciones y posibilidad, a cúal mas interesante:

- Usando el puntero y añadiendo el *offset* relativo. Podemos usar la función estandar `offsettof( )` para ello, contenida en `<stddef.h>`:

  ```
  scanf( "%s", (char *)( ptr + offsetof( struct dummy, buffer ) ) );
  ```
- Usando el *azucar sintáctico* que C nos ofrece para acceder a miembros de `struct` a través de su puntero, lo cual hace que sea mas *agradable* visualmente. Fíjate que en realidad estamos haciendo **exáctamente lo mismo** que en el caso anterior.

  ```
  scanf( "%s", ptr->buffer );
  ```
- Si, como en el caso expuesto, el *desplazamiento relativo* es `0`, pues podemos *abreviar* el tema :-)

  ```
  scanf( "%s", (char *)( ptr ) );
  ```

Answer (score 3):

A `scanf()`hay que pasarle como segundo parámetro (o terecero, etc. si hay más de uno) una dirección de memoria, pues es en esa dirección donde va a dejar el dato reccogido del teclado.

Cuando lees una variable de tipo entero, o float, es habitual usar `&variable` para obtener la dirección de memoria donde está esa variable, y pasarle esa dirección a `scanf()`.

Cuando lees cadenas, en cambio lo más habitual es tener un puntero apuntando a una zona de memoria donde pretendes leer la cadena (aunque este no es tu caso), por ejemplo así:

```
char *nombre;
nombre = malloc(20);  // Reservar sitio para 20 caracteres
```

En este caso, ya que `nombre` es un puntero, se llamaría a `scanf()` con:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
```

pues *el valor* de `nombre`  ya apunta a la zona donde queremos dejar los datos. No se debe usar aquí `&nombre`, pues en ese caso los datos se guardarían *en el puntero*, en lugar de *en la dirección a que apunta el puntero*. Naturalmente eso estaría mal, ya que el puntero no es lugar donde guardar caracteres.

En tu caso lo que tienes es un array de char:

```
char nombre[20];
```

Ocurre que en C, el nombre de un array como parte de una expresión equivale a la dirección de memoria donde está el primer elemento de ese array. Es decir, si pones:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
```

el compilador ve:

```
scanf("%s", &nombre[0]);
```

y en ese sentido se puede omitir el `&` delante de un array cuando queremos obtener su dirección.

Es más, `scanf("%s", &nombre)`, si te pones purista, es incorrecto desde el punto de vista de los tipos, ya que `&nombre` nos da la dirección del array en lugar de la dirección del primer elemento del array. Aunque ambos son al final la misma dirección, sus tipos no coinciden, ya que `&nombre` es un *puntero a array de caracteres*, mientras que `&nombre[0]` (o `nombre` a secas) es un *puntero a carácter*.

#### **Nota sobre seguridad**.

Usar `scanf()` para leer cadenas es inseguro porque típicamente tu cadena tiene un tamaño limitado (20 en este caso), pero a `scanf()` no le dices el número máximo de caracteres a leer. El usuario podría introducir más de 20 con resultados imprevisibles. Se recomienda usar [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) en su lugar, que sí permite especificar un máximo de caracteres a leer, así:

```
fgets(nombre, 20, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas arreglos o cadenas, el nombre de esa variable hace referencia a la dirección, asi que puedes usar los dos, por ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    char cadena[4] = "uno";

    printf("Dirección cadena %x\n", cadena);
    printf("Dirección &cadena %x\n", &cadena);
    printf("Dirección &(cadena[0]) %x\n", &(cadena[0]));

    printf("Valor cadena %s\n", cadena);
    printf("Valor &cadena %s\n", &cadena);
    printf("Valor &(cadena[0]) %s\n", &(cadena[0]));


}
```

Imprimirá lo siguiente:

```
Dirección cadena 30b39710
Dirección &cadena 30b39710
Dirección &(cadena[0]) 30b39710
Valor cadena uno
Valor &cadena uno
Valor &(cadena[0]) uno
```